# Best way to upload file using Stream

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am calling REST API which is accepting Stream to upload file from local device, so for that right now I am using following code to get Stream from a file and than closing that stream after it get's uploaded:

```
var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

The problem with the above approach is that, until entire file gets uploaded to server user don't have any chance to delete that file because stream of that file is open, what would be the solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the maximum file size you expect?

Comment: There is no size limit for that, It can be of any size.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to delete the file before it is uploaded, you have to create a copy. Try copying it to a temporary file, upload this instead and then delete the temp. file. Or use the good idea, that Kirill had ;-)

Comment: @Jens Copying file to a temporary is not a good approach, as sometimes it might possible that I don't get chance to perform cleanup.

Comment: Can you write down your exact requirements and give them a very good look until you realise they are mutually exclusive? From your question and comments, paraphrased: _"user must be able to delete a file that is being uploaded"_, _"I cannot copy the files to a temporary location because I may not be able to clean up"_, _"I cannot load the entire file in memory because they can potentially be larger than what fits in RAM"_. Please explain why you want your user to be able to delete a file while that file is being uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

If your typical file is reasonably sized (and I'm hoping you won't be uploading 2GB+ files to a REST API), you could always just read the stream into memory and before feeding it to your API, like so:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0; // Reset to origin.

    // Now use the MemoryStream as you would a FileStream:
    api.Upload(memoryStream);
}
```

Another alternative is to create a temp copy of the file on your hard drive and feed that to the API - but then dealing with cleanup can become a bit cumbersome. `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` is your friend and may very well suffice for your purposes, but it still offers no bulletproof guarantees.

Comment: I already thought of using that approach, but what If user don't have enough memory for such operation?

Comment: @zee Then temp files are the way to go - but be prepared for a headache getting file cleanup to work reliably in the face of potential exceptions, concurrent uses of the application on the same UNC share / under different Win users on the same machine etc.